# Where do I find Flex plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 9.0 on a MAC?

Tags: apache-flex, plugins, intellij-idea

I have read about the wonders (and sometimes bugs) of working with flex in IntelliJ. I though the Flex pluggin was alredy installed in the Community Edition 9.0.2 version of IntelliJ, but to my surprise I can't find it. Not in the installed plugins nor in the available ones. Nothing. I followed the directions in [this tutorial](http://insideria.com/2010/02/intellij-idea9-actionscript-3f.html) but on the part where he enables the Flex support I just don't find my plugin.

I also tried to look it up without succes. I understand the plugin is called Flex Support and should be available for Mac. Any ideas where to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not available in the Community edition, please refer to the [IntelliJ IDEA Editions Comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Install IDEA Ultimate to get Flex support.